# Possible to add pending options to custom action?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Is it possible to add a custom action to `state: 'PENDING'` on a custom action for a timecard?

I would like the ability for the user of my app to tap and add a title to something for a custom 'Favorite' action on my timecard while the progress bar is filling (like when sharing a photo or video).

Answer (score 1):

When adding a custom menuItem, there are three states that you can provide values for, one of which is mandatory:

- `DEFAULT` - Default value shown when displayed in the menuItems list.
- `PENDING` - Value shown when the menuItem has been selected by the user but can still be cancelled.
- `CONFIRMED` - Value shown when the menuItem has been selected by the user and can no longer be cancelled.

To implement your use-case, simply provide the `iconUrl` and the `displayName` to show when the menuItem is in its `PENDING` state.

Comment: Is it possible to implement another menu that can be accessed when tapping during the `PENDING` state though?  I want my user to tap during the state and be able to attach a caption that will send with the custom action.

Comment: This feature does not exist with the Mirror API; feel free to file a feature request in our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).